# Get just one result from an ArrayCollection (Twig)

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig

I'm working on an audio player with a playlist for a Symfony project, everything is ok except I can't get title of the track who is played.

From my query, I have an array of tracks (tracks from a specific album ):

```
array:6 [
▼

  0 => Track {
#752 ▼

    -id: 1
    -title: "Dragon"
    -track: "Bzoark.mp3"
    -trackFile: null
    -createdAt: DateTime {
#758 ▼

      +"date": "2017-08-10 09:39:00.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "UTC"
    }
    -updatedAt: DateTime {
#755 ▶
}
    -album: Album {
#555 ▶
}
  }
  1 => Track {
#733 ▶
}
  2 => Track {
#768 ▶
}
  3 => Track {
#771 ▶
}
  4 => Track {
#774 ▶
}
  5 => Track {
#777 ▶
}
]
```

The problem is, when I do this on my twig file, I have a list of all my tracks names (which is normal).

```
<div class="song-info">
   <span class="artist">{{ album.artist }}</span>
   <span class="song">{% for tracksList in tracks %}{{ tracksList }}{% endfor %}</span>
</div>
```

Is there a way to get the name of track playing only ?

Here a [screenshot of that problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xdbc.png) (front end):

I'm using Js/Jquery (audioJs) audio player to play tracks.

I'm not really sure it's possible (from twig) but there is maybe another solution to do this ? (from js ?)

Thanks for help!

Comment: Set another attribute such as a boolean (`isPlaying`) to true and display only that. Since you are using a for loop - it in indeed going to display all song titles in the array over which you are iterating

Comment: As @Jaya said, your track object should have an attribute where you could control that. Regards

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure to understand, I need to add an attribute on my entity "Track" ? If so, how can I manage that new attribute in my template twig, if it's a true boolean, I need to change it to false when another song is played.

Comment: You don't need to use `twig` to fill in this information. You need to determine which song is playing with `JS`

Comment: Key, so you need in JS to set up a variable which knows the name of the track which is currently playing (should be updated at every "play" - every double click on the song).  You can populate that span with the name of the current song using jQuery. I personally prefer Angular 1.x when I have a lot of frontend logic.

Comment: Thanks guys, so I'm going to try that with JS as I soon as I have time!

Answer (score 0):

if you use a js to control playing, it is easy to use js to get the name of track or do some loop  and control click to your span with js to get the name from class attribute